# Can you add superuser and stackoverflow hosts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, login

The logging-in between Stack Exchange sites that have different domain names does not consistently work.

Can you just add superuser and stackoverflow hosts, so that

> superuser.stackexchange.com

and

> stackoverflow.stackexchange.com

will work?

*(And of course add hosts for the other Stack Exchange sites that have their own domains.)*

***UPDATE #1:*** I performed some research, and the above-described failure is likely due to browsers being configured to not accept third-party cookies. Since this is very common nowadays, I recommend just adding a few more hosts to the stackexchange.com domain.

***UPDATE #2:*** It looks like the most upvoted answer is incorrect. That answer claims that adding superuser.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.stackexchange.com "wouldn't do any good". But there are 100+ other Stack Exchange sites that show that it does work perfectly (for example https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and https://android.stackexchange.com/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/), so I'm not sure why this erroneous claim is being promoted.

Given that this technology *does* work (which we can't always say!), how do we make it help Stack Exchange instead of hurting it? The answer is simple: add the new hosts (such as `superuser.stackexchange.com`), but also keep the existing sites exactly as they are (i.e. `superuser.com`). Then add a simple user-preference toggle to allow users to choose whether to route to `superuser.stackexchange.com` or `superuser.com`.

This can be a win-win. The content on `superuser.stackexchange.com` will be identical to `superuser.com`, and it will allow people who actually contribute to Stack Exchange (which is a tiny minority - most people only visit but don't contribute) to have a more seamless experience.

Make no mistake, `superuser.com` and `stackoverflow.com` will still be the primary advertised sites. But for those contributors who don't allow third-party cookies (really, does anyone still allow those?), we will have a more seamless and usable Stack Exchange experience (which will lead to even more contributing, which helps build Stack Exchange).

`superuser.com` has had a review backlog for quite some time. As a top 10 reviewer of that site, I can tell you I would perform many more reviews if I didn't have to provide login credentials again just for that site.

Comment: Uh - what do you mean by "logging"?

Comment: I assume he means login, but I've never had a problem with it what's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Um, logging in to a site.  When you log into one stackexchange sites, you are automatically logged into all of the ones that use the stackexchange,com domain.

Comment: @PeterJ It doesn't work for all the SE sites that don't use the stackexchange domain.  I've reported it to SE in the past.

Comment: You are on Safari?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, I don't hunt endangered animals.

Comment: What browser and OS are you on (with versions please)?

Comment: It works just fine for me.

Comment: Yes, i also face the same issue many times.

Comment: @Sandeep - can you share details? Is this happening at work? School? What browser and OS are you using and what versions?

Comment: @Oded Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m, win 7.  Whenever i login into StackExchange and change to Code Review stack(or any other) using top left dropdown , i should be by default logged in. But this is not happening i have to once again login into code review. This thing OP asked.

Comment: @Sandeep - when you say "login to StackExchange", what *exactly* do you mean? Logging into openid.stackexchange.com or something else?

Comment: @Oded It was a typo, my mistake `Login to http://stackoverflow.com/.`

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all, @Sandeep . Is this happening at work? School? Home?

Comment: @oded Where are you trying ? work? School? Home?

Comment: @Sandeep - trying to figure out what network setup you (and the OP) have - given that most people don't see this. Wondering if this is a corporate/school network that might be blocking some traffic causing this issue. I am connecting from home, but when at work also not seeing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/991/discussion-between-sandeep-and-oded).

Comment: This happens to me as well. Just checked askubuntu.com and it doesn't have me logged in at all. Safari 9.0.3 (10601.4.4) on OS X 10.10.5

Comment: @Oded This issue only occurs when i login using Gmail account i,e if i login to SO using red google button on login page.

Comment: @Sandeep - do you have any plugins/add-ons that might interfere with that (privecy/ad blockers and such)?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I haven't been able to reproduce the issue you have stated.  I did notice that you "joined" a lot of communities yesterday - is that the real question?  Why do I need to click "join"?

Comment: "really, does anyone still allow those?" - Yes. Statistically speaking, almost everyone does. That's why we very, *very* rarely hear about any problems with global login. You're trying to propose a domain addition as simple - I assure you it's far from simple. This proposal includes a tremendous amount of code changed (for example: checking every link we generate everywhere) to fix an *extremely* small *opt-in* breaking case. The root cause of this issue isn't that a 2nd domain doesn't exist, it's that browser functionality is disabled and things don't function as a result.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard let me be crystal clear then: 99.999% of our users have them enabled. I was trying to be kind by not saying your trouble case (of disabling them) is statistically insignificant, which is true.

Answer (score 19):

> Can you just add superuser and stackoverflow hosts

Yep, we *could*, but it also wouldn't do any good. Since when your browser goes to the *actual* domain, it wouldn't use those cookies. Some of these actually exist from the olden days. For example: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

You'll note that the domain is strictly a redirect, as such others must be as well. Given that your cookie would only be used (and ignored, because it makes no difference) on a 301/302, there's not much point in such a domain.

If the proposal is to make `stackoverflow.com` now be `stackoverflow.stackexchange.com` and send all traffic there, then the answer is simply: no, that isn't going to happen.

The bottom line here is that if browser functionality is disabled, it will be less functional. In this case, that's cross-site login. Re-enable third-party cookies or whitelist our domains in the disable to get that functionality back.

Comment: So [tag:status-declined]?

Comment: Just FYI, the proposal is *not* to make stackoverflow.com now be stackoverflow.stackexchange.com and send all traffic there.  There is a much more elegant way we can handle it, if it would fix the issue.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard it works on all of those because the cookie is on `stackexchange.com`. I'm not sure I follow your "more elegant" way - do you want to clarify a bit?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard yes it would absolutely work - but it would never happen. That would (probably quite literally) kill our company and end Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Adding a redirect from stackverflow.stackexchange.com to stackoverflow.com wouldn't work far as login goes. Making stackoverflow.stackexchange.com the primary domain for SO *would* make login smoother, but also break a ton of other things (SEO, brand recognition, etc - Haney has a list in his answer), so we are not going to do that.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for bringing this up. Login across sites requires 3rd party cookies, since by design not all of our sites are subdomains of stackexchange.com (and we won't entertain that idea for good reasons). You've disabled 3rd party cookies, therefore the cross-site login system that depends on 3rd party cookies doesn't work. So your current options are to re-enable 3rd party cookies (or just whitelist ours), or login again on our top level domains.

**EDIT:** to elaborate on "good reasons" which seems vague, here are some specific reasons:

- Top level value of stackoverflow.com and superuser.com (the same reason you don't find Google at google.alphabet.xyz)
- Brand value and identity (people know stackoverflow.com and superuser.com)
- Canonicals and Google page rank. A majority of our traffic comes from Google search. Google penalizes you for duplicate page content on multiple sites and domains. This is part of how they combat those sleazy domain parking click pages and prevent them from appearing in results.
- A 301 / 302 redirect from these subdomains would just be an extra superfluous step which wouldn't help your problem. While the subdomain might keep the cookie, the redirect would lose the 3rd party cookie.
- This kind of a change would be massive, and all to mitigate the real problem of avoiding 3rd party cookies, which is arguably not a problem and is part of the modern HTTP / browser spec.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - canonicals means that a page has one canonical URL - that it doesn't change, that the same page doesn't have multiple URLs that are all correct. In regards to search engines - do you really think that someone like Google will simply change how their search engine works just because we "communicate" with them? I have no idea what you are talking about with your meta tags - meta tags are not headers - and your solution has nothing to do with pagerank.