# Bug? Constantly logged out of "Super User" despite being logged in to SE

Tags: bug

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

I am logged in to SE and can use most of my communities, but when I go to Super User it keeps showing me as logged out and asks me to sign up or log in to participate in discussions.

I tried clearing site data (cookies and such) for *superuser.com* and I have cookies approved for the site. All of my other communities can be accessed normally, either via the my communities drop down or via URL/websearch (and Super User is still listed in my communities drop down with my reputation and all).

I just tried a manual sign-in to SU with success, but it still seems like strange behavior to be signed out of only one SE site.

Comment: Ah so this is a side effect of SE foolishly allowing sub-sites to have vanity domain names rather than enforcing a uniform community.stackexchange.com format. 
My remain-logged-in settings must have been obscuring this behavior.

Comment: No, this is because SE has refused to send the HTTP header that allows cross-domain cookies to work. This used to work in the past when browsers simply accepted such cookies, but today it doesn't work, and the team is either unaware that they can simply send a header to make them work or it would require more work (the staff answer there says it would, but I don't know if they're aware that it can be fixed with a header since they didn't respond to my comment about it).

Comment: Without the vanity plates.it would not be an issue in the first place, regardless of how easy you estimate the fix would be. No added complexity or work-arounds is the simplest and easiest solution of them all.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Don't adblockers block cross-domain cookies? They should; cross-domain cookies seem like a powerful tracking technique. In this case, sending headers won't solve the problem for adblock users, but changing the vanity domains would.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ad blockers and browsers alike have long supported allowing specific things through them. Also, when it comes to the domains, they were established long before it was ever thought there would be a network of sites, let alone before the current model of cross-site authentication was established in 2015. Changing the domains now would break quite a few things; see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277224/377214) to a past feature request asking for this - the first three bullets there are unrelated to cookies.